# Why does this Vue app work on Codepen but not my localhost

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am a beginner at VueJS and I am working on my first app. I am having trouble getting the data bindings to work on my localhost.  I am using Axios to pull a JSON API for rocket launches and am able to output the data points on a codepen, but when I move the identical code to my localhost, the bindings no longer work.

The API call returns the data, and I am able to log it to the console, but the actual data bindings are not being output in the HTML at render.  I am including the scripts for axios and vue.  I have tried including them in the head and before the close body tag.  I have also tried to make the script linked and inline. The Vue method is running, or I wouldn't get the data returned from the API call, so I am convinced there is some knowledge about VueJS that I am missing.  What could that be?

Here is the code from my localhost that doesn't work:

```
    <div id="launches">
        <section class="launch" v-for="launch in launches">

            <h3 class="rocket">{{launch.rocket.name}}</h3>
            <p>Rocket: {{launch.rocket.name}}</p>
            <p>LSP: {{launch.lsp}}</p>
            <p>Webcast: {{launch.vidURLs[0]}}</p> 
            <p>NET: {{launch.net}}</p>
            <p>Location: {{launch.location.name}}</p>

        </section>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const vm = new Vue({
          el: '#launches',
          data: {
            launches: []
          },
            mounted() {
                this.getLaunches();
            },
            methods: {
                getLaunches() {
                    axios.get('https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch?next=5&mode=verbose')
                        .then((response) => {
                            this.launches = response.data.launches;
                            console.log(this.launches);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {console.log(error); });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the codepen that works just fine: https://codepen.io/titanean/pen/GxvYYq

**EDIT:** My build process (Grunt) was stripping out the data bindings for some reason.  Code is working fine.

Comment: Did you check the console in developer tool for any errors?

Comment: @Taki Yes, there are no errors in the console or in the Vue devtools.

Comment: clear the cache, then load the page again.

Comment: Not a cache issue.  I have caching off, and I clear cache almost every time I reload.

Comment: I guess you're importing Vue before the script that you're showing us, right?

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero Yes, The VueJS import is currently happening in the head, while this script is called inline before the closing body tag.  I've tried it almost every way I can think of to make sure it isn't some dependency issue.  I'm currently calling Axios, then VueJS, then my script.  Axios is making the server call, its returning a response, and the method is logging the response to the console properly.

Comment: Do not import Vue in the head, do it right before the closing body because Vue wouldn't find your #launches, since It will not exist at that time.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero Yeah, that's the way I initially had it set up, but it didn't make any difference. I reverted it back to just before the closing body, and it still isn't working.

Comment: Please share your whole HTML.

Comment: I believe I just figured out what is happening. I am running a grunt bake process to inject script references, which is working fine, but it appears that my Grunt build process is stripping out my Vue data bindings on build.